# Do we really need an [hmacsha1] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I recently came across the [hmacsha1](/questions/tagged/hmacsha1) tag, and was originally going to suggest that it be renamed to [hmac-sha1](/questions/tagged/hmac-sha1) (since running the two acronyms together like that just looks silly).  However, after thinking about it a bit more, I wonder if we really need that tag at all.  Basically, all it amounts to is the intersection of the existing [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) and [sha1](/questions/tagged/sha1) tags.

Before I start manually retagging 84 questions, though, I'd like to ask if anyone has any better suggestions.  In particular:

- Do you agree that [hmacsha1](/questions/tagged/hmacsha1) is a useless intersection tag, and should be replaced with [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) and [sha1](/questions/tagged/sha1)?
- Is there any easier way to do that than manually editing all the tagged questions?

Comment: *Do you agree that `[hmacsha1]` is a useless intersection tag?* No. This is like saying `[jquery-ui]` is a useless intersection tag that should be replaced with `[jquery]` and `[ui]`

Comment: @NullUserException: But [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) means something more specific than a user interface made with jQuery. HMAC-SHA1 does _not_ really mean anything more specific than [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) instantiated with [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

Comment: Tags are meant to make it easier for people to find questions. Now imagine we split the tags and someone wants to find a question about HMAC instantiated with SHA-1. I just think it's unreasonable to expect them to know they should search for `[hmac] [sha1]`. If an `[hmac-sha1]` tag is present, it's obvious.

Comment: @Null: OK, I guess we just disagree on that, then; it doesn't really seem at all unreasonable to me. (That's why I asked this question, so thanks for your comments.) Ps. How about at least renaming the tag to add the hyphen, then? That at least would be an improvement, whether or not the eventual consensus is to keep the tag or not.

Comment: @Null: I just put a bounty on this old question to get some more opinions on it. Feel free to include yours, whether or not it's still the same as before.  (Also, I apparently can't spell "third opinion" in the bounty message... *\*slaps forehead\**.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, six days after posting the bounty, the vote total for this question is now at **+8** / **−1**.  I take that to mean that, out of the apparently limited number of people who even care either way, at least a fairly large fraction do seem to agree that [hmacsha1](/questions/tagged/hmacsha1)  should be replaced with [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) + [sha1](/questions/tagged/sha1).

Accordingly, I'm going to start retagging the questions soon.  No promises on how long it's going to take, but it's only a little over 100 questions, so hopefully not too long (even if the manual retagging process *is* rather labor-intensive for something so simple).