# How often do users make use of tags in searches?

Tags: discussion, tag-search

This site hosts many discussions about tags. [here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164128/do-we-really-need-an-hmacsha1-tag) an example. These discussions are sometimes predicated on the idea that users really type tags, [] and all, into the search box.

I find this this notion hard to swallow. It seems to me that most people are finding their way here with Google, and the rest are just typing some terms into the box. Especially since the improvements to the search engine of a few months ago.

If I'm correct, than the highest use of the tags is to allow would-be answerers to filter for things to look at. (Aside from the possibility of letting us just add a Lucene query string to our profiles to define what we want to look at.)

Are there stats on how the search box is used?

Comment: FWIW, I do very often.

Comment: I use it, but sometimes I find it a little clumsy.. as in I am never sure if I have typed the tag correctly (is it [windows8] or [windows-8] or [windows.8]...) It would be nice if there was an auto-complete feature.

Comment: I'm not sure these statistics would be very relevant or meaningful. While I agree, I'm curious, I don't think it will have any bearing on what features we implement or how the site operates.

Comment: I do this ... but exclusively for site maintenance. I think [se] still has a bit to go before they have Google's search engine beat.

Comment: Personally, I do it often when I know the tag.  When I don't know exactly how the tag is spelled, I will go there through the tag page (`/tags`)

Comment: I do it quite a bit, particularly using a combination of tags with and without negation: `[foo] [toto] -[bar]`, and particularly with the same few tags I am most interested in.